# python Msql connection with fetchone gives error

Tags: python, database

I've got a weird problem. I've made a vba code in excel, that calls a python code that get information from the excel sheet and put it into a database. Yesterday there was no problem. Today I start my computer and tried the vba code and it errors in the python file.

The error:

```
testchipnr =  TC104
Traceback (most recent call last):
testchipID =  108
File "S:/3 - Technical/13 - Reports & Templates/13 - Description/DescriptionToDatabase/DescriptionToDatabase.py", line 40, in <module>
TestchipID = cursorOpenShark.fetchone()[0] # Fetch a single row using fetchone() method and store the result in a variable., the [0] fetches only 1 value
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

The weird thing is that there is a value in the database -> testchipID ...

My code:

```
#get the testchipID and the testchipname
testchipNr = sheet.cell(7, 0).value # Get the testchipnr
print "testchipnr = ", testchipNr
queryTestchipID = """SELECT testchipid FROM testchip WHERE nr = '%s'""" %(testchipNr)
cursorOpenShark.execute(queryTestchipID)
print "testchipID = ", cursorOpenShark.fetchone()[0]
TestchipID = cursorOpenShark.fetchone()[0] # Fetch a single row using fetchone() method and store the result in a variable., the [0] fetches only 1 value
```

Comment: But testchipnr seems to be a number why are you putting it inside the quotes in your query? `'%s'`? Just remove the quotes if its an integer -->`%s`

Comment: Hi, testchipnr is not an integer. It is something like TC104

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying, it was working fine but now it is not, the only reason that I can think of is when your query is returning Zero results.

Looking at your code, if your query is returning only one result, then it will print the result and the next time you are making the call to `cursorOpenShark.fetchone()` to store in `TestchipID` it would return None.

Instead, can you try the following code

```
#get the testchipID and the testchipname
testchipNr = sheet.cell(7, 0).value # Get the testchipnr
print "testchipnr = ", testchipNr
queryTestchipID = """SELECT testchipid FROM testchip WHERE nr = '%s'""" %(testchipNr)
cursorOpenShark.execute(queryTestchipID)
TestchipID = cursorOpenShark.fetchone()[0] # Fetch a single row using fetchone() method and store the result in a variable., the [0] fetches only 1 value
if TestchipID:
    print "testchipID = ", TestchipID[0]
else:
    print "Returned nothing"
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't make any sense. I've put the 'print "testchipID = ", cursorOpenShark.fetchone()[0]' in the code to shw you the result, to show that it wasn't empty. Now I tried your code, and suddenly it works. So i've tried the original code (just copied the one from this morning) and it works. Is it possible that the link to the database takes time after the computer starts up, or something? I really don't think there is a problem in the code rather then a databaseconnection? Thanks for the help! I'll see if it works tomorrowmorning ^^

Comment: Every fetchone gives you the next result in the cursor and as such you should not make the call twice like you did as that will essentially skip a record from the result. I cannot comment on the state of database but if the program is unable to make a connection you will get error when you execute the query. Hope this helps

Comment: If your issue is solved, could you close this question?

Comment: Hi, I still got the issue. And this time there is no print in the code. It is the same code as last time when posting this question. It worked, but now again, it doesn't. I really have no clue what it could be, I don't think it is the code, but I don't know enough of databases and the connections to it to search for the cause.

Comment: Did you made the change or you are referring to your old code?